# Calculus or Rates Question, Grade 11 Class

Tags: calculus

This came up in the introduction to a Grade 11 math course that does not cover calculus. I believe this can be solved using calculus (although I can't figure out how), but is there another way? Both paths to a solution would be appreciated, because I'm not even positive what kind of question this is. Here is the question exactly as it is written (including grammar errors):

A metal rod is being heated at rate described by the equation:

Q = 6t + 4 (where t is time in seconds)

If the rod is initially 16[degrees]C find the temperature of the rod after 5 seconds.

---EDIT---

I believe the answer to the above question is supposed to be 111, if that helps.

Here are two more questions that I believe are meant to be solved the same way, I also have answers from the source (but it just gives the numbers, with no other context). Again, these are copied verbatim and there is no other information given.

The rate at which a bucket is being filled with water is given by the equation:

B = 6t^2 - 6t - 1 (where t is time in seconds)

If the bucket is initially empty, find the volume of water when t = 2.

ANSWER: 2L

---

The rate at which a dam is being filled can be found using the equation:

W = 9t^2 + 4t + 2 (where t is the time in hours)

If the dam initially contained 11,181 liters, find the amount of water in it after 6 hours.

ANSWER: 11,913L

Comment: This might not be your fault, but the way the problem is asked, it seems that we're lacking information. If we're given the received heat Q, we need the rod's thermal capacity to deduce the change in temperature ...

Comment: What does $Q$ mean?  I gather it is the function $Q(t)=6t+4$ but what does that function measure? It can't be the temperature at time $t$ as we have $Q(0)=4$ and you tell us that the rod starts out at $16$ degrees.

Comment: You need to use the first law of thermodynamics.

Comment: @MrYouMath The thermal capacity isn't given though

Comment: @Hippalectryron: Maybe these are also missing in the problem text.

Comment: What's included with the question is all the context that was given, I agree that it seems that not enough is given - but I thought I was just doing it wrong. I have some other examples (with answers this time, which may help a lot) that I've edited into the original question. I'm fairly sure they're meant to be solved in the same way.

Comment: Hi Justin. I showed you the calculus way in my answer below. Quick question. Do these problems come from a unit/section in which acceleration, velocity, and position were discussed. In particular, did you see the equation $y = -\tfrac{1}{2}gt^2+v_0t+y_0$, or something like it?

Comment: The answer you provided is exactly what I needed, thank you! I actually contacted the creators of the content and these questions on 'rates of change' were accidentally included in a section intended to review 'rate of change' (slope). Your answer makes them all solvable now, though, which is very satisfying. Thank you so much, I have marked it as correct but cannot rate until I resolve an issue with my account/email. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, let $T(t)$ be the temperature of the rod at time $t$. Then the rate of change of the temperature is $\tfrac{dT}{dt}$, the derivative of $T(t)$. But we are given the rate of change is $Q = 6t+4$. Therefore,
$$\frac{dT}{dt}=6t+4.$$
Using integration (i.e. finding the antiderivative of $6t+4$), we find that
$T(t) = 3t^2+4t+T_0,$
where $T_0=16$ is the initial temperature of the rod. Hence we have,
$$T(t)=3t^2+4t+16$$
is the temperature of the rod after $t$ seconds. Note that $T(5) = 111$.

The other problems are solved in the same way: by taking the antiderivative of the rate and using the initial condition.